# Can Linux mDNS client be "pure" client?

Tags: linux, mdns, zeroconf, avahi

I found some famous mDNS clients, such as nss-mdns, Avahi-browse, are dependent on avahi-daemon. However, if we start avahi-daemon, the client machine also publish its mDNS domain name and become a mDNS server. Is there a mDNS client in Linux that only does the client job?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [avahi-daemon.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/avahi-daemon.conf):

> Section [publish] disable-publishing=
>
> Takes a boolean value ("yes" or
> "no"). If set to "yes", no record will be published by Avahi, not even
> address records for the local host. Avahi will be started in a
> querying-only mode. Use this is a security measure. This option
> defaults to "no".

---

So if you edit `/etc/avahi/avahi_daemon.conf` with

```
[publish]
disable_publishing=yes
```

and restart the service (e.g. `service avahi-daemon restart`), avahi will stop responding to mDNS requests.